Querying Data in Python
I have seen a number of posts, but none seem to quite answer what I am after. Please note that I am currently working under the constraint of only having the standard Python classes available.
The general problem I wish to solve is to find items in a list given query parameters based on a variable query pattern. i.e. (and please treat the following as pseudo code) the solution may get a request to

find all rows in a list that match where element[1] == 2 and element[3] != 5,

The next request might be to

find all rows in a list that match where element[6] == "Bob" and element[7] != None and element[12] >= 0

And the request after that might be a completely different query. In other words, I don't how many or which elements and what conditions might be requested.
More specifically, I am trying to identify as set of rows in a CSV file given any query based on the columns therein. I'm not precious on the data structure, I'm just struggling to find a good way to perform something similar to an SQL query (in function). Due to the data in the csv being inconsistent over time, and changing business needs, it would be a bad idea to hardcode conditions into the code as they would become outdated.
Hopefully this is possible using the standard classes
I haven't really tried anything other than a lot of Google searching and bumping into examples using hard coded conditions a lot. I have been focusing on lists a lot and this might be my issue.
I suspect I can cycle through each element of the query against each element of a row in the csv, over and over, but how would I deal with all the various comparators? - sounds like a lot of coding that someone has likely already done in a nice neat little function (I hope!)

@TomKarzes - Yes they are entered by someone, but not directly into the Python solution. The expectation is that they will be contained in a file and that there will be many of them. Entering them into the solution would take too long and be too prone to error. The file then gives them the ability to add/update/remove queries as needed. Not wedded to a file, but this is the rationale to not entering by hand each time

@TomKarzes - So my interpretation of your answer is that filter as a string - no built in function and syntax to do this? If they're not coming in as strings, what other, more simple to implement options are there?

You don't want to use the builtin SQL module for some reason?

@Jeyekomon - I'm not actually working with a SQL database, I just needed query/SQL like functionality. Sash' solution below led me to eval(), which for some reason I had not come across at all.

You're not working with a SQL database... but you could. My idea was to create a simple database from your data in that CSV file and then you can apply any SQL queries. Creating a database from CSV file shouldn't be that difficult. But the eval approach is also doable. Might be a bit less scalable but probably enough for your needs.

@Jeyekomon - Completely agree :) I don't have the luxury of SQL being available to me at this point. I suspect we will need a more scalable solution, so you're right to raise it. The work I'm doing is evolving into a proof of concept as more is understood about the real problem.

Maybe you can try a hack using eval().
Depending on how much you trust your users you add some restrictions to the global and local variables they have access to, but if it is just trusted internal users just  it:
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Any


def query_data(data: Sequence[tuple[Any, ...]],
               condition: str) -> Sequence[tuple[Any, ...]]:
  """Returns a list of tuples that match the passed in condition."""
  return [row for row in data if eval(condition)]


csv_data = [
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    (1, 2, 3, 5, 5),
    (10, 9, 8, 7, 6),
    ('Alice', None, 'Bob', 0, -1),
    ('Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 0, 1),
    ('Daniel', None, 'Evan', 1, 0),
]
print(f"""{query_data(csv_data, 'row[1] == 2 and row[3] != 5') = }""")
print(f"""{query_data(csv_data, 'row[0] == "Bob" and row[1] is not None and row[3] >= 0') = }""")
print(f"""{query_data(csv_data, 'row[4] > 0') = }""")
print(f"""{query_data(csv_data, 'isinstance(row[0], str) and row[0].startswith("A")') = }""")
print(f"""{query_data(csv_data, 'row[1] == None') = }""")

Output:
query_data(data, 'row[1] == 2 and row[3] != 5') = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
query_data(data, 'row[0] == "Bob" and row[1] is not None and row[3] >= 0') = [('Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 0, 1)]
query_data(data, 'row[4] > 0') = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 5, 5), (10, 9, 8, 7, 6), ('Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 0, 1)]
query_data(data, 'isinstance(row[0], str) and row[0].startswith("A")') = [('Alice', None, 'Bob', 0, -1)]
query_data(data, 'row[1] == None') = [('Alice', None, 'Bob', 0, -1), ('Daniel', None, 'Evan', 1, 0)]


Thank you Sash. Will give this ago. Appreciate the reply :)

Hi Sash - eval() was the missing link. I do not know why hours of googling never brought me to this method. Fortunately you have, thank you. My solution did not need Sequence or Any, but it was good to see them used. Perhaps this would be a good way to refactor my code if I get time. Thank you again! :)

Here's the outline of a simple solution. Assuming that the CSV file is loaded into a list of dictionaries representing rows, each dictionary maps column headers to corresponding values.
def dynamic_query(rows, conditions):
    """
    Perform a dynamic query on the list of rows based on specified conditions.
    conditions is a list of tuples, where each tuple contains (column_name, operator, value).
    """
    filtered_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        if all(compare(row.get(col_name), op, value) for col_name, op, value in conditions):
            filtered_rows.append(row)
    return filtered_rows

def compare(value, op, target):
    """
    Compare value with target based on the specified operator.
    Supported operators: "==", "!=", ">", "<", ">=", "<=", "notnull", "null".
    """
    if op == "==":
        return value == target
    elif op == "!=":
        return value != target
    elif op == ">":
        return value > target
    elif op == "<":
        return value < target
    elif op == ">=":
        return value >= target
    elif op == "<=":
        return value <= target
    elif op == "notnull":
        return value is not None
    elif op == "null":
        return value is None
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported operator: {op}")

Example queries as described in the question using lists of tuples:
query1 = [("column1", "==", 2), ("column3", "!=", "5")]
query2 = [("column6", "==", "Bob"), ("column7", "notnull", ""), ("column12", ">=", "0")]

# Perform queries
result1 = dynamic_query(rows, query1)
result2 = dynamic_query(rows, query2)

The results returned are the list of rows matching the conditions.

Thank you Dan. Will give this ago. Appreciate the reply :)

This was really useful, particularly for seeing how simple it is to parse the comparators. I wish I could mark two answers as helpful (I don't have enough reputation to vote :( ) as this truly was, but Sash's nod towards eval() is what cracked the problem for me. Thank you for you help.
